# Introduction to computer algebra systems?

Tags: math, symbolic-math, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

Does anybody know of any resources (books, classes, lecture notes, or anything) about the general theory of computer algebra systems (e.g. [mathematica](http://wolfram.com), [sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/))?

"Introductory" materials are preferred, but I realize that with such a specialized subject anything is bound to be fairly advanced.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"General Theory" of CAS is a pretty huge scope for a question.  That being said, I'll do my best to cover as much as I can in the hopes that something helps you find what you're looking for :)

The proceedings of the ISSAC and SIGSAM groups would no doubt have some good stuff about techniques for building CAS systems.  A list of various topics in the general area of CAS building is available here: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/algebra.html

If you're more looking for information on how to code some of the math involved, I'm a fan of the "Numerical Recipes" series; it provides sample code and a reasonably decent explanation of math in a wide range of topics.  Last I checked, an online version of an older revision of the book was available here: http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php (Note that this is the "Numerical Recipes in C" form of the book; there are versions in other languages as well).

For building a CAS in general, one place to start might be here: "Building a computer algebra environment by composition of collaborative tools" by Kajler and Safir; Another place you might check is here: http://www.math.wpi.edu/IQP/BVCalcHist/calc5.html where a high-level description of how a few folks implemented a CAS is listed.

The other thing you might try is diving into the code for a few of the open source CAS projects that exist: YACAS (Yet Another Computer Algebra System : Java), Axiom, etc.  I like the list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems

Hope something in there was useful!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll check the links out and maybe pester you for some more info in the future.

Answer (score 8):

The basics are nicely covered in [PAIP](http://norvig.com/paip.html); the source code is [free online](http://norvig.com/paip/) -- see particularly the source files with 'macsyma' in the name. Topics include rewrite-rule systems, simplification using canonical forms, integration and differentiation, and compiling and memoizing rewrite rules for speed.

Answer (score 6):

I've found Algorithms for computer algebra by K.O. Geddes... to be pretty useful.  I'm a junior undergrad with a light math background doing work on OpenAxiom (a CAS).  Get ready for some heavy, heavy math though, my best advice is to have a couple books if only to have a different perspective if you get "stuck".

It might help if you suggest what you're looking into, what areas you're interested in, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two books which describe algorithms used for implementing computer algebra systems:

[Computer Algebra and Symbolic Computation: Elementary Algorithms](http://web.cs.du.edu/~jscohen/ElementaryAlgorithms/index.htm)

[Computer Algebra and Symbolic Computation: Mathematical Methods](http://web.cs.du.edu/~jscohen/MathematicalMethods/index.htm)

I used these books to implement libraries for computer algebra in Scheme ([MPL](https://github.com/dharmatech/mpl)) and C# ([Symbolism](https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism)).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one link from Wikipedia: [Computer Algebra Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system)
And another here: http://www.math.wpi.edu/IQP/BVCalcHist/calc5.html

Answer (score 2):

You mention [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) in your question so I'll speak to that briefly.

The project and community of SymPy are themselves actually very good resources.

1. There is a variety of expertise that regularly checks and responds to the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/sympy).
2. The code is openly available [on github](http://github.com/sympy/sympy).
3. The [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org) is fairly complete and often includes academic citations.

If you're interested in CASs come on by. The contributors like to talk about what they work on. If you're interested it's [easy to get started](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Development-workflow) and add your own contributions.